# Time complexity of nested loops?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

Can anyone help me to calculate and explain me time complexity of this algorithm :

```
function mystery(n)
    r := 0
    for i := 1 to n − 1 do 
        for j := i + 1 to n do 
            for k := 1 to j do
                r := r + 1 
    return(r)
```

Comment: Is `return(r)` supposed to be outside the loops? If so please fix your indentation.

Comment: Have you attempted the problem? Usually people are more willing to help if you can explain your attempt.

Comment: The return value of the function gives the complexity. It is not hard to prove that the function returns *n³/3 - n/3*, and thus it is *O(n³)*.

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea how to make sigma character on StackOverflow but it will be:

```
Sigma(i=1; n-1)Sigma(j=i+1; n)Sigma(k=1;j)1=Sigma(i=1; n-1)Sigma(j=i+1;n)j
```

you can simplify the inner Sigma by:

```
Sigma(j=i+1; n)j = Sigma(j=1;n)j - Sigma(j=1;i)j = n(n-1)/2 - i(i-1)/2=n^2-i^2+n-i
```

then you have:

```
Sigma(i=1; n-1)n^2-i^2+n-i
```

It will be `O(n^3)` but get my answer more as a tip than solution

Comment: `Sigma(i=1; n)=n(n+1)/2` Where does this come from?

Comment: 1+2+3+...+n = n(n+1)/2
I would prove it by induction

Comment: Yes but that would be `Sigma(i=1; n) i`, but you don't have a sum over `i`.

Comment: Oh, typo, sorrry, I'm editing

Comment: I don't think you understand what I'm trying to point out. Where in the original problem did you get a sum over `i`?

Comment: Well, I just presented this this formula to let @TungVuDuc know where did it come from. It's really unconfortable to write pure math on StackOverflow btw

Comment: I know how to solve this problem, but I can't understand your answer. That makes me think your answer is very confusing. The expression `Sigma(i=1; n)i=n(n+1)/2` has no logical connection to the rest of your answer, so I don't know why it's there.

Comment: I don't understand the line `Sigma(j=i+1; n)j = (n+i+1)(n-1)/2`

Comment: Do you think it's more clear now?
@pkpnd I just wrote this formula to let op know what I used to count inner Sigma. Probably it wasn't clear.

Comment: @Michu93 Your answer now makes more logical sense, thanks.